# Import Laravel vue application into nativescript vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nativescript

I have currently built a large scale laravel application with vue js scaffolding as its front end and now I am planning to use nativescript vue to build a mobile application for it.

As far as I have researched I have gone through with testing nativescript sidekick application and vue cli for creating web and mobile projects but I have no idea on how to import an existing project so that I can use my laravel web app backend as a backend for my nativescript application too.

Can anyone please explain me the process on how I can get started ?

Comment: Irrespective of what your backend is, all communication with the backend and Vue / NativeScript application would be via REST APIs.

Comment: So I can just create a new nativescript vue project and communicate with my web application logics through my api's and simply solve the issue altogether ?

Comment: Yes. that's how it typically works.

Comment: Well, That was what I had in mind too but I just thought there was some other solution that I just dnt see... But hey thanks for clearing my doubts.